# Utility to manage multiple python scripts

Tags: python

I saw this post on Medium, and wondered how one might go about managing multiple python scripts.

[How I Hacked Amazon's Wifi Button](https://medium.com/@edwardbenson/how-i-hacked-amazon-s-5-wifi-button-to-track-baby-data-794214b0bdd8)

This describes a system where you need to run one or more scripts continuously to catch and react to events in your network.

My question:  Let's say I had multiple python scripts that I wanted to do run while I work on other things.  What approaches are available to manage these scripts?  I have to imagine there is a better way than having a large number of terminal windows running each script individually.

I am coming back to python, and have no formal training in computer programming, so any guidance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear in the extreme how the blog you link to relates to your question. Is this just spam to attract clicks to the blog?

Comment: It's not my blog.  The post on Medium shows a simple script, which is easy to follow.  However, if the aim was to constantly monitor network traffic, how would you actually run this script.  Moreover, my question stems from the need to run many similar scripts at once.  I suppose you can have multiple terminal windows, but that seems ineffecient

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully clarify the background as well as your actual question. Please review, and obviously feel free to fix or revert if you feel it came out wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I had multiple python scripts that I wanted to do run. What
>   approaches are available to manage these scripts? I have to imagine
>   there is a better way than having a large number of terminal windows
>   running each script individually.

If you have several `.py` files in a directory that you want to run, without having a specific order, you can do:

```
import glob
pyFiles = glob.glob('path/*.py')
for pyFile in pyFiles:
    execfile(pyFile)
```

Comment: I didn't think of that.  What happens when one may error out?  Does it break the entire chain?

Comment: @Btibert3, yes. You may want to use Exception Handling in that case. You can also run all these script in parallel, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your system already runs a large number of  background processes, with output to the system log or occasionally to a service-specific log file.

A common arrangement for quick and dirty deployments -- where you don't necessarily want to invest in making the scripts robust and well-behaved enough to run as proper services -- is to start the script  inside `screen` or `tmux`. You can detach when you don't need to be looking at it, and can reattach at any time -- even from a remote login -- to view the output, or to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw today the [script server of bugy](https://github.com/bugy/script-server). Maybe it might be a solution for you or somebody else.

(I am just trying to find a tampermonkey script structure for python..)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at luigi (I've not used it).

https://github.com/spotify/luigi

These days (five years after the question was asked) a lot of people use docker compose.  But that's a little heavy weight depending on what you want to do.